# Android Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have finally made sample phonegap project running but as I want to change something in index.html, it gives me this error.

```
 [2012-08-11 17:04:46 - s] W/ResourceType( 9484): Bad XML block: header size 60 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
    [2012-08-11 17:04:46 - s] C:\Users\TOomo\workspace\s\res\layout\activity_test.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
    [2012-08-11 17:04:46 - s] C:\Users\TOomo\workspace\s\res\menu\activity_test.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings').
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

you must have define Strings new_game in values like

Your String
 Your String

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

You can create values xml file -If you are using eclipse then right click on the project and select other and there select android xml file,then given window select resource type as value,

Answer (score 0):

Click on your "res" folder and go to "values".  Open the file called "Strings".  Make sure you have set a string called "hello_world" and another called "menu_settings" in there.